# DatePicker in Fragment Android didn't show

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog, android-datepicker

My code in fragment :

```
public class DatepickerFragment extends Fragment {
TextView etDate;
static final int DATE_ID = 0;
Calendar C = Calendar.getInstance();
private int mYearIni, mMonthIni, mDayIni, sYearIni, sMonthIni, sDayIni;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        mYearIni = year;
        mMonthIni = month;
        mDayIni = dayOfMonth;
        etDate.setText(mDayIni + "-" + (mMonthIni + 1) + "-" + mYearIni + " ");
    }
};

 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), mDateSetListener, sYearIni, sMonthIni, sDayIni);
    }
    return null;
}

    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_datepicker, container, false);
    etDate= rootView.findViewById(R.id.etDate);

    sMonthIni = C.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    sDayIni = C.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    sYearIni = C.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    etDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().showDialog(DATE_ID);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

I am trying this code for activity and then is success, but I try in Fragment datepicker didn't show. My fragment is in the slider viewpager, and I try with fragment dialog and the viewpager adapter is error.

How to show DatePicker in Fragment?

Comment: You can't override both `onCreateView` and `onCreateDialog`. If you want to show a dialog from your fragment, you need another fragment, a DialogFragment.

Comment: Avoid setting click listeners etc in onCreateView method ..do that in onViewCreated method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**make your fragment implement to DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener**

**create a calender instance for current date**

**create DatePicker dialog and show**

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment implements android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

/**
 * Create new fragment.
 */
public static YourFragment ofNew() {
    YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment, container, false);
    Button button = rootView.findViewById(R.id.show);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showAndroidPicker();
        }

        ;
    });
    return rootView;
}

private void showAndroidPicker() {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
            this, year, month, day);
    datePickerDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {

}
}
```

Comment: Your code is error, and error result is "Class 'DatepickerFragment' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onDateSet(DatePicker, int, int, int)' in 'OnDateSetListener'".. Please help me

Comment: Did you make your fragment class implement the listener onDatesetlistener ?

Comment: yes i make onDatesetlistener in my implement fragment

Comment: Okay let me check again

Comment: Yes.. i hope you success.. and you notif me :)

Comment: are you using any library?